# Connecting IQ Index Service to Elasticsearch authenticated with OAuth

Tags: microservices, authorization, tridion-docs, elasticsearch

We have an existing Elasticsearch instance which is only accessible through an endpoint authenticated with OAuth. In our new Tridion Docs 13 SP2 installation, we are trying to configure or IQ Index Service to index via this Elasticsearch endpoint. However, looking at the [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20Docs-v1.1.2&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-88805652-C5D3-4585-B6E7-C3D746C39617&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-8B90BDCC-E1BC-461F-9D25-222028718162.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-88805652-C5D3-4585-B6E7-C3D746C39617), it seems this may not be possible, as the IQ Index Service configuration only allows the following:

- es.host
- es.port
- es.username
- es.password

OAuth typically works by first requesting a token and then using that token to connect to the main endpoint, which means the IQ Index Service would need to be configured with 2 endpoints (token + Elasticsearch instance), but the configuration only allows for one (es.host:es.port). So does anyone know if it is possible to connect the IQ Index Service to Elasticsearch, in this scenario? And if so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `IQ Combined Services` (Index and Query) are designed to work with Elastic Search present in the DXD Stack. `Index service` indexes the data in Elastic Search and `Query Service` is used to query the data out of the Elastic Search. Both the services operate on the same Elastic Search instance.

Currently, Index Service doesn't support OAuth authentication but basic authentication only. Which in most cases is sufficient considering Elastic Search is a part of the DXD stack.

If you want to index the data in an Elastic Search instance which is out of DXD stack and uses OAuth, I'd suggest implementing a `Custom Storage Extension` at DXD end which Index the data on every publish transaction. The extension first obtains the Oauth Authentication Token before sending the Index Request to the Elastic Search.